# How to add a new column to a 4d numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to add a new column to my image dataset.

Sample Code:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.arange(240).reshape(3,4,4,5)
print(type(A))
print(A.shape)
B = np.concatenate([A, np.ones((A.shape[0],4,4,5,1),dtype=int)], axis=1)
```

print(B.shape)

Gives error:

```
ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions
```

## Context:

Consider this as m samples of read images (nH=height, nW=Weight, nC=channels). 
Dataset is of shape (m, nH, nW, nC )and now I want to add additional column reflecting the image is of "good" example or "bad" example of an object.

Thus, want to create a dataset with label added in the dataset to form shape : (m,nH,nW,nC,l)  where l stands for label and can have values either 0 or 1.
How can i achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: A is 4d, and the 'ones' is 5d

Comment: When A.shape = (3,4) , then
np.ones((A.shape[0],1),dtype=int) is what is used.

tried with all possible options, somehow cannot get the right set of dimensions for adding a new column.
np.ones((A.shape[0],4,4,5,1),dtype=int)
np.ones((A.shape[0],4,4,5),dtype=int)

Comment: @bharati You want to add one value per image, but a shape of `(m,nH,nW,nC,l)` implies that this information is present for **every pixel** in the image stack. Are you aware of that? It may be more useful to keep two separate arrays (a stack of images and a list of labels).

Comment: There's confusion about what 'one more column' means.

Comment: yes @kazemakase, I am aware of it. Just that I want to stack them together so that i could reshuffle the data before splitting and still not worry about ensuring labels are still valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even simpler without reshaping :

```
A = np.random.rand(3, 4, 4, 5)
B = A[None]           # Append a new dimension at the beginning, shape (1, 3, 4, 4, 5)
B = A[:,:,None]       # Append a new dimension in the middle, shape (3, 4, 1, 4, 5)
B = A[:,:,:,:,None]   # Append a new dimension at the end, shape (3, 4, 4, 5, 1)
```

Basically, the position of *None* indicates where to add the new dimension.

Comment: Thank you!  This helps add the new dimension as I wanted. Reading more on your suggestion, came to know np.newaxis could be used to add new dimension on nd array.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add the fifth column explicitly. Just reshape and add the fifth dimension.

```
import numpy as np
A = np.arange(240).reshape(3,4,4,5,1) # add the fifth dimension here
print(type(A))
print(A.shape)
```

To set the "good" or "bad" label, just access the last dimension of A

Comment: Thanks makes sense. However, the shape of B now is different
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
A-> (3, 4, 4, 5, 1)
B-> (3, 8, 4, 5, 1)
Any idea why the second dimension doubled?

Comment: I edited the answer to fit with what you really want.

Comment: The dimension that doubles depends on the axis in the concatenate command. Axis=5  - will make last dimension as 2.
B = np.concatenate([A, np.ones((A.shape[0],4,4,5,1),dtype=int)], axis=4)

print (B.shape)

Comment: I am trying to create the last dimension on A so that i could use it later.